# Transversality of graphs of functions

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider the $C^1$ function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.  I understand that a curve in the plane that intersects the graph of $f$ non-transversally would be tangent to it at a point of intersection.  I also understand that transversal intersection of submanifolds is generic.  My question is, by viewing the graphs of two functions as submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can I then state the following:

> The set of all functions in $g \in C^1([0,1])$ whose graph intersects the graph of  $f$ non-transversally are meagre?

I suspect this is a very simple question; I'm relatively new to differential topology and was hoping somebody could set me straight with some intuition!

Comment: What does it mean for graphs of functions that are merely continuous to intersect transversely?

Comment: @JackLee  I suppose its a very strong abuse of notation to call it that.  Consider, for example, the graph of $|x|$ and the x-axis.  It has the geometric intuition I'd guess of transversality but not the differentiability component.  It's probably a very poor choice of words to even describe it as such.

Comment: There's a big difference between piecewise $C^1$ and $C^0$ :)

Comment: These have all raised good points and it seems the edited secondary question is poorly founded.  I have removed it in light of the feedback.  Any thoughts on the first though? Is this the right way to think?